# Why does my XML Parser keep iterating through the tags in Swift?

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing

I'm trying to parse through weather data in XML format, but my parser seems to be iterating through all of the tags instead of the one I specify. 
So, I have in my didStartElement function:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
{
    if(elementName == "cap:event") {
        capEventFound = true
    }
}
```

and my didEndElement function:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    if(elementName == "cap:event") {
        capEventFound = false
    }
}
```

my parser function:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    if(capEventFound)
    {
        newsStories.append(string)
        print(newsStories)
    }
    else
    {
        print("No cap:event found")
    }
}
```

Other relevant functions for parsing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pvState.delegate = self
    self.pvState.dataSource = self
    stateCode = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return stateCode.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return stateCode[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    selectedState = stateCode[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
    url = "http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/\(selectedState).php?x=0"
    urlStr = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
    searchURL = NSURL(string: urlStr as String)!
    xmlParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: searchURL)!
    xmlParser.delegate = self
    xmlParser.parse()
}
```

My output for example when I choose Colorado is here: http://pastebin.com/v3ULvQ0G

Why is it doing this and how can I get it to only post the relevant cap:event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's continuing to iterate through tags because it's never calling `didEndElement`. This is because your `didEndElement` declaration is not correct, and therefore isn't getting called like you expected. This declaration:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) { ... }
```

should be:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) { ... }
```

---

Unrelated, but your process that appends values in `foundCharacters` is a little dangerous because it's theoretically possible that it will require multiple calls to `foundCharacters` to return the full event name. You should generally only append characters in `foundCharacters`, and do the updating of your model structure in `didEndElement`. For example, I might suggest:

```
var parsedString: String?

// element starts

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if elementName == "cap:event" {
        parsedString = String()
    }
}

// characters found
//
// this may be called more than once

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    parsedString? += string
}

// element ended
//
// but, by the time we get here, we have the full parsed string 

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "cap:event" {
        newsStories.append(parsedString!)
        parsedString = nil
    }
}
```